# get sum of numpy array when another array equals 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

im trying to create a custom scoring function but I am having trouble with the last line.

```
def scorer(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred1 = shift(y_pred,1)
    y_pred2 = shift(y_pred,2)
    target = y_pred - y_true
    action = np.where(target > 0, 1, 0)
    diff = y_pred2 - y_pred1
    score = (action == 1).sum(diff)
```

My output is supposed to be the sum of the diff rows when the action is equal to 1 for that row.

| Diff | Action |
| --- | --- |
| 1.28 | 1 |
| 2.56 | 0 |
| .64 | 1 |
| .32 | 0 |
| 5.12 | 0 |

For example, in this case it would be 1.28+.64=1.92

Comment: needs  a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in particular, what is the output you see currently and what is the output you expect?

Comment: something along `diff[action==1].sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the diff directly into the `np.where`:

```
action = np.where(target > 0, y_pred2 - y_pred1, 0)
```

then sum `action`, via

```
sum(action)
```